# Python EEL module resizing

Tags: python, user-interface, resize, eel

I am creating python application and for its GUI purpose I am using HTML, CSS and JS. For combining all I am using EEL package in python. I am successfully able to create application. But i am facing problem for resizing. When user resize it at smaller sizes then the GUI becomes fully disturbed and the data were not able to fit in that space.

I have also tried this `eel.start("index.html", size=(720, 480))`

So, I want that user can resize the dimension of window as he or she wants but user should not go below minimum width of 720px and minimum height of 480px.

Any one with proper solution please help!!!

I have also tried this `eel.start("index.html", size=(720, 480))` but it didn't works

I want that user can resize the dimension of window as he or she wants but user should not go below minimum width of 720px and minimum height of 480px.